# Singular integral operator

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, compact-operators, singular-integrals

i got the following problem to solve.

Let  $0 < \alpha < 1$, $L \in L_\infty([0,1]^2)$, $D = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x = y\}$ the diaagonal of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $k:[0,1]^2 \setminus D \to \mathbb{C}$, $k(x,y) = \frac{L(x,y)}{\vert x-y \vert^\alpha}$.

Then $T_k: L_2[0,1] \to L_2[0,1], (T_kf)(x) = \int_0^1 k(x,y) f(y) dy$ is well-definied and compact.

For the first part my Idea was to show that $k(x, \cdot) \in L_2[0,1]$, so i can use Cauchy–Schwarz inequality and Fubini thereom to show that $T_kf \in L_2[0,1]$. Hence I would like show that $\int_0^1 \vert k(x,y) \vert^2 dy < \infty$ for a fixed $x \in [0,1]$. But I'm not sure how to bound $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\vert x - y \vert^{2 \alpha}} dy$ for a fixed $x \in [0,1]$. Am I on the right track or is this idea useless? And if I'm on the right track, how can i show that?
For the second part i got no real idea, how you can show easily that $T_k$ is a compact operator. I would be grateful for some help on the topic.

Comment: Wouldn't we need $\alpha<\frac12$ for $y\mapsto |x-y|^{-2\alpha}$ to be integrable on $[0,1]$?

Comment: That was a question i also encountered during my investigations. But honestly i don't know. Because maybe there is a compeletely other way to see that $T_k$ is well-defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $C=\max\{\|L\|_{\infty}^2,1\}$. Assuming that $\alpha<\frac12$, we may compute
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\int_0^1|k(x,y)|^2\ \mathsf dy\ \mathsf dx &= \int_0^1\int_0^1 L(x,y)^2|x-y|^{-2\alpha}\ \mathsf dy\ \mathsf dx\\\\
&\leqslant C \int_0^1\int_0^1 |x-y|^{-2\alpha}\ \mathsf dy\ \mathsf dx\\
 &= 2C\int_0^1\int_0^x (x-y)^{-2\alpha}\ \mathsf dy\ \mathsf dx\\
&= 2C\int_0^1 \left(\frac{x^{1-2 \alpha }}{1-2 \alpha }\right)\ \mathsf dx\\
&= \frac C{(1-\alpha)(1-2\alpha)}<\infty,
\end{align}
so that $L_k$ is a Hilbert-Schmidt operator. It follows that $L_k$ is compact.

Comment: That is quite a nice trick to solve the integral like this. I'm don't know what a Hilbert-Schmidt operator is. Is there a way to see the Compactness elementarily?

Comment: A bounded operator $A$ on a Hilbert space is a Hilbert-Schmidt operator if $$\sum_i \|Ae_i\|^2<\infty, $$ where $\{e_i\}$ is an orthonormal basis. It's been a couple years since I took operator theory so I'm a bit rusty; perhaps someone else will provide an alternative argument.